# TypeError: delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'trip_id'

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I've created a GUI using tkinter with python ,one of the functions pf this GUI allows the user to delete data from mysql ,but i got this error.

```
def delete(e):
    trip_id=e.get()
    mycursor.execute("DELETE FROM trips WHERE trip_id=%s",[trip_id])
    mydb.commit()
    mycursor.execute(" DELETE FROM stop_times WHERE trip_id=%s",[trip_id])
    mydb.commit()

def delete_trip():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Delete a trips")
    top.geometry("600x300")
    lbl1 = Label(top, text = 'trip_id:', font = {'Helvetica',10})
    lbl1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.1)
    entry1 = Entry(top)
    entry1.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.1)
    button1 = Button(top, text="Delete a trip",command=lambda:delete(entry1))
    button1.place(relx=0.5 ,rely=0.5)
```

Comment: I don't think this code will give that error. For one, `delete` doesn't take a positional argument named `trip_id`, and for another, you're passing a positional argument to `delete` so it won't throw any error related to arguments.

Comment: Yes ,i can't see any problem with this code but i allways get this error

Comment: You cannot get this specific error with this specific code. If you need help, you need to provide an actual [mcve] that generates the error. Maybe you have another `delete` method defined somewhere else in your code, but _this_ code won't throw that error.

Comment: Thank you ,I made a mistake by creating two functions with the same name delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code should work. Are you sure you don't have another (different) definition of the “delete” function somewhere else in your code?

Also, the name “delete” is very generic and might lead to confusion and subtle bugs (like this one). That can be avoided by using more specific names.  In this case, it might be better to name the function “delete_trip” or similar.

Comment: I already found another function named delete with more parameters .Thanks